# What's the right parallelism-factor for AKKA Thread Pool Executor running in docker

Tags: akka

I have 15 apps running in containers in a single host. My apps are using the default thread pool size based on the number of CPUs it detect, which is what the host is exposing (16), however I'm allocating 1 CPU per app (using mesos) I know these are only cpu-shares and not full CPUs, but I don't think my apps should be configured to the default values for CPU related settings (I'm already defining max memory per jvm).

What is the right value for: parallelism-factor, parallelism-max, in AKKA  thread pool executor?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`parallelism-factor` is capped by `parallelism-max` (and `parallelism-min`, essentially the result of `max(parallelism-min, min(parallelism-max, cores * parallelism-factor)`) so if you want to limit downwards you only have to set `parallelism-max` to a low value.

Sounds like a low value should fit better given the single logical core. The default is set, with a single core more than one threads will essentially just compete against each other, but on the other hand, if there is a little bit of blocking somewhere unexpected it is good to have some extra threads. I'd go with four or possibly eight and benchmark the application a bit.